# How to hide the <li> tag using php based on certain condition?

Tags: php, html

In the below code, i used to check the deadline date and todays date, if the deadline date is greater then i will give the register option otherwise hiding the register option. but in either case the register is shown`

```
<?php 

$today= Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$qry="SELECT RegDeadline FROM admin where username='root'";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$Dealine= $row[0];


   if(strtotime($today)>strtotime($Dealine)) ?>
        <li><a id="reg" href="form_stud.php"><h4> <p class="text-primary"> Register Student  </p> </h4></a></li>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the format of the mysql date ? Please post an example

Comment: what does `$today` and `$Dealine` print?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way  (echo the `li` only if the `if` statement is true) :

```
<?php 
    $today= Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $qry="SELECT RegDeadline FROM admin where username='root'";
    $res=mysql_query($qry);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $Dealine= $row[0];
    if(strtotime($today)>strtotime($Dealine)) { 
       echo '<li><a id="reg" href="form_stud.php"><h4> <p class="text-primary"> Register Student  </p> </h4></a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **brace**

Try this;

```
<?php 
$today= Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$qry="SELECT RegDeadline FROM admin where username='root'";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$Dealine= $row[0];
   if(strtotime($today)>strtotime($Dealine)) { ?>
        <li><a id="reg" href="form_stud.php"><h4> <p class="text-primary"> Register Student  </p> </h4></a></li>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: OP should get error for missing the brace in the code, isn't it? Rather said form shows anyways

Comment: You can use if condition without brace (that's why no error) but he should not close PHP tag. I assume when he close php tag, if codition finishes and <li> shown anyway.